# WebTest Plugin not used when the Webtests are in a folder

Tags: visualstudio, web-testing

Following a problem I had with TLS connection I found out that when a WebTest is located inside a folder it wont use the custom WebTestPlugin that is set in the WebTest.
Is there a fix for this problem?

I am using VS2013

Answer (score 1):

Adding the DLL the plugin is compiled in (In my case the same project as the WebTest) to the TestSettings deployment will solve the issue and the WebTest will be able to use the custom plugin.